# Extensions containing the Schur cover

Tags: gr.group-theory

Given two finite groups $G$ and $H$ such that $H$ is a perfect subgroup of $G$, is there always an extension of a finite group by $G$ such that the image of $H$ under the extension is isomorphic to the Schur cover of $H$?

Comment: Is $H$ a perfect subgroup the same as $H$ a subgroup and $H$ perfect? Also I think you mean "inverse image" rather than "image".

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No; the map is from $G$, not to it.

Comment: The map from $G$ to an extension by $G$ is injective, so the image of $H$ is $H$, so how can it also be isomorphic to the Schur cover of $H$?

Comment: How are you defining injectivity for general maps?

Comment: $f$ is injective if, for all $a,b$, $f(a)= f(b)$ implies $a=b$. But maybe a simpler point is that the image of $H$ by an arbitrary map has cardinality at most the cardinality of $H$, while the Schur cover has cardinality greater than the cardinality of $H$ as soon as the Schur multiplier is nontrivial.

Comment: Oops. I had my terminology mixed up. I was trying to talk about relations, not maps.

Comment: So you want to know if, given any $H\leq G$, there exists an extension $\hat G$ of $G$ with quotient map $q:\hat G\to G$, and a subgroup $X$ of $G$, such that $X$ is isomorphic to the Schur cover of $H$ and $q(X)=H$? The answer to this is 'no', and counterexamples abound. I can provide one if you need it, and this is what you mean.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven not quite. $H$ must be a perfect group and $\hat{G}$ must be finite.

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $H=A_7$ and $G=A_8$. Then the Schur cover of $H$ is $6\cdot A_7$, but the Schur cover of $G$ is only $2\cdot A_8$. Any extension $3\cdot A_8$ would have to be a direct product, and of course that does not restrict to the non-split extension $3\cdot A_7$.

Comment: $3^7 \cdot A_8$ isn’t a direct product, although it probably doesn’t contain $3 \cdot A_7$.

Comment: @DanielSebald Ah, you want to also include the option that there is some $3\cdot A_7$, not that it is the full preimage. I am sure that is the case that there is no such extension either, but what I wrote above definitely does not prove that.

Comment: Your comment doesn’t seem to address mine…

Comment: @DanielSebald The point is that any extension where the inverse image of $A_7$ is $6 \cdot A_7$ would have to be an extension of $A_8$ by $\mathbb Z/6$, and, since there is no. nontrivial action of $A_8$ on $\mathbb Z/6$, would have to be a central extension. So there is no need to consider other extensions like $3^7 \cdot A_8$.

Comment: Oh, I just realized my mistake.